# Quoted string not properly terminated Exception

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I was updating password in an oracle databse using a java servlet like this

```
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps,ps1;
ResultSet rs;
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Drivers Not Found");
            }
try{
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SharedCryptography", "fyp", "fyp");


}catch(SQLException e1)
{
}
String query="UPDATE tbGroup SET GPassword='"+mypassword+"' where GName='"+GroupNamee+"' and OEmail='"+OwnerId+"'";
java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

But it gives java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Am i doing something wrong in it?Please help

Comment: Does one of your values have a single-quote character in it?

Comment: @rgettman which value you are talking about ?

Comment: This is what happens when programmers don't escape query parameters properly. You should really use prepared statements

Comment: @BackSlash what you mean?Please help

Comment: [Check oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @user3445854 Does any of the values you're concatenating into your SQL statement contain a single-quote character?

Comment: @rgettman no they dont.

Comment: @BackSlash i think instead of providing further links you should help here only

Comment: @user3445854 His links and advice are correct. If you are unwilling to read the links, it doesn't seem likely that you'd be willing to read our answers here either, as all we are doing is echoing information that already exists because you don't feel like reading it. Also, print out the actual query you're generating and look at it.

Comment: BTW: You should reconsider using the OTHIN pure-JDBC driver instead of ODBC bridge to access Oracle. It is faster and more reliable. (Only problem: you might need to configure URL/User/Pass in Java instead on system level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should absolutely avoid string concatenation in SQL statements. You will get in all kind of security and stability problems. Your problem is simply be resolved by using a prepared statement:

```
String sql="UPDATE tbGroup SET GPassword=? where GName=? and OEmail=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, myPassword);
ps.setString(2, groupName);
ps.setString(3, ownerId);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

If  you do this, no "'" or "%" or "_" or " in your parameters will cause any problems. Alternatively you can try to escape your characters, but why bother - the PS method is not only more robust and easier to read, it is often also more performant.

For a general description of the security problems, see: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

One of your variables (probably password) has a quote  or semi colon in it.  Since you build up your query via String concatenation, you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  It looks like you accidentally attacked yourself via injection.  If you had a properly maliciously formatted variables you could have done quite a bit of damage to your database.

Please use Parameterized queries

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE tbGroup SET GPassword= ? where GName= ? and OEmail=?" )

stmt.setString(1, mypassword);
...
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

See this for more details

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: In this PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE tbGroup SET GPassword= ? where GName= ? and OEmail=?" ) from where to give value to second and third question marks ?

Comment: Yes the ? is the placeholder for the variables which you set later with `setString( index, value)`  For some silly reason the numbering starts at 1 instead of 0.